# Run Background Task in Django (Threading)

Tags: django, multithreading, django-admin

I declared a class inherited `threading.Thread` in django which requests a url and saves an object according to and it works perfect on my computer but when i uploaded to server, Thread was just working makes a response to my main request and after that, thread destroys

```
AddModelThread(movie_id).start()
```

executes when i request the server and after my response the thread destroys!

in my `Thread` i request a website(using `requests` class python) then i save an object

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is async tasks - celery can help you with that

Comment: If it is possible i want to use python main threading class! @at14

Comment: Celery is usually the way to go. I highly recommend against trying to do this by yourself. Django's philosophy is DRY (dont repeat yourself). If you do go down the path of managing this by python threading you will be opening a new database connection for each thread so do be sure to close the connection, there are several other things that you will have to take care of. There are several other questions on stacker flow about python threading which you can use as reference

Comment: @at14 but how does Celery makes threads?! does it not use `threading.Thread` class?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) just like me now :-)

and to answer my question :

all i needed to do was adding `--enable-threads` arg to the uwsgi on the server (fortunately i figured out after meeting Celery)